# When has a diagonal operator closed range?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory

Consider a bounded sequence $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of scalars and consider the diagonal operator
$$T: \ell^2 \to \ell^2: (a_1, a_2, \dots) \mapsto (b_1a_1, b_2a_2, \dots).$$
I want to prove that $T$ has closed range if and only if
$$c:=\inf\{|b_n| : n \ge 1, b_n \ne 0\}> 0.$$

I managed to show that this condition is sufficient. However, I cannot prove it is also sufficient. I tried to proceed as follows:

If $c=0$, I tried to construct a convergent sequence in $T(\ell^2)$ such that the limit does not live in $T(\ell^2)$. For simplicity, let us assume that $b_n \ne 0$ for all $n$. Then it would be sufficient to show that there exists a sequence $(c_n) \in \ell^2$ such that
$$\sum_n \frac{|c_n|^2}{|b_n|^2}= \infty$$
because then the sequence
$$(c_1b_1^{-1}, 0, \dots,), (c_1b_1^{-1}, c_2b_2^{-1}, \dots), \dots$$
of $\ell^2$-vectors would do the job. Of course, other approaches will be appreciated as well. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is fine. If $c=0$, you can choose a subsequence $\{b_{n_k}\}$ such that $|b_{n_k}|<2^{-k}$. Let
$$
c=\sum_k b_{n_k}\,e_{n_k},
$$
where $\{e_n\}$ is the canonical basis. We have $c\in\ell^2$. We cannot have $c=Tx$ for some $x$, because necessarily $x$ would be $x=\sum_ke_{n_k}$, which is not in $\ell^2$. But $c=\lim_K\sum_{k<K}b_{n_k}e_{n_k}$ is in the closure of the range of $T$.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks.